# Get index direction from information schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, information-schema

Suppose I created index with descending order

```
CREATE INDEX `MyTable.MyIndex`
USING BTREE ON `MyTable` (`DateFrom` DESC, `DateTo` DESC);
```

I want to get information about it from `information_schema`.

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/statistics-table.html) `information_schema.statistics` table does the job.
However I can't find any information about column order for indexes (i.e. `ASC` or `DESC`).

How can I find that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For MySQL version < 8

Where is it written in the documentation that the table statistics does the job ?

Furthermore, I found in [the create index doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) this:

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC.
> These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage.
> Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

Comment: > Where is it written in the documentation that the table statistics does the job ? The STATISTICS table provides information about table indexes. (from link in question)

Comment: I checked the docs today again and for mysql 5.7 the specs on ASC and DESC will be allways ignored

Comment: DESC indexes are now supported in mysql 8, and so this question is still unanswered (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this query ....

```
SELECT   non_unique,
         index_name,
         seq_in_index,
         column_name,
         collation,
         cardinality,
         sub_part,
         packed,
         nullable,
         index_type,
         comment
FROM     information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE    table_schema = schema()
AND      table_name   = 'MyTable'
ORDER BY index_name,
         seq_in_index
```

Comment: I think the better way to do this is `show indexes from table_name;`. Also, there is no column here is which specifies the order i.e. `ASC` or `DESC`.

Comment: This is the correct answer for 5.7+

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-statistics-table.html