# Get index direction from information schema in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql

I just want to reiterate this question found here: [Get index direction from information schema in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947197/get-index-direction-from-information-schema-in-mysql), since Mysql 8 supports descending index. How do you know whether the index is DESC or ASC ?

The [SHOW INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html) query seems to have a lot of information, but not the direction.

Comment: See `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS` - `COLLATION`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statistics-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually I overlooked the documentation (thanks to @Akina for pointing the right direction), here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html,
it's basically the collation property that gives this information.